# Stop PostgreSQL from starting on Windows?

Tags: postgresql, windows-vista

I have a local postgresql database for development purposes that I dont want to start up every time Windows does - how do I stop it from starting!

Answer (score 50, accepted):

If it is running as a Windows service:  Start -> Run -> (then type in:) services.msc.
Scroll to PostgresSQL services, double click and set them to manual instead of automatic.

[image]

If you do need them again, just fire up services.msc again and click the Start icon/button once you have reselected the PostgresSQL service.

Comment: will it somehow affect how postgresSQL works? I don't want to have Postgres running in background when I don't need it, but I also need it to work properly when I'm working with it. What will change if I set that service to `manual`?

Comment: @Piotrek When a service's Startup type set to Manual Windows doesn't start it after reboot. Automatic services are all [attempted to be] started after reboot.

Answer (score 13):

You can check this [out](http://www.garretwilson.com/blog/2014/03/09/postgresql-management-windows.xhtml)

Type **services.msc** as previously mentioned and read the path-to-executable as follows;

[image: Services.msc capture]

Path to executable: "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.3\bin\pg_ctl.exe" runservice -N "postgresql-x64-9.3" -D "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.3/data" -w

Net service name is defined as **postgresql-x64-9.3**

So simply, whenever I want to shut down postgresql, I just type the following on a command line instance (to create a cmd instance, type **windows+r** and enter **cmd**);

```
net stop postgresql-x64-9.3
```

If you run another version of postgresql, you can just check the service name as explained and use this as a shortcut. Hope that it helps.

Comment: Some comments:  1. for Windows 7 services run `msconfig`  2. cmd run as Admin

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer didn't work for me because everything is greyed out and I can't disable anything.

If you have the same issue, it could be due to privileges.

You will need to launch CMD as an admin user:

- Open Start, type: CMD
- Right click CMD
- Click Run as administrator

Then you can disable PostgreSQL by running the following commands:

```
sc stop postgresql-x64-13
sc config postgresql-x64-13 start=disabled
```

Replace 13 with your PostgreSQL version number. You can find the service name by running:

```
sc query
```

Of course the better solution is to install Linux ;)

Answer (score -2):

This question is old and already answered, but this might help someone.
From Windows Command line
Start:
NET START postgresql-x64-9.2

Stop:
NET STOP postgresql-x64-9.2

Change your version and windows. This is for 64-bit windows, version 9.2.

Comment: How does this prevent postgresql from starting when Windows does?